# Grouping records by categorical criteria

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, grouping

I came across the following problem - have table with this structure.

| user_id | permission |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | Denied |
| 25 | Permitted |
| 139 | Denied |
| 139 | Limited |
| 139 | Limited |
| 139 | Limited |

It is necessary to group records by categorical criteria (3 categories) into **one line** for "user_id", counting different states of "permission". It should look like this:

| user_id | denied_count | limited_count | permitted_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 139 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

I tried to do grouping using group by and case with this script:

```
select user_id, 
       permission, 
       case when permission = 'PERMITTED' then count("permission") else 0 end as permitted_count,
       case when permission = 'LIMITED' then count("permission") else 0 end as limited_count,    
       case when permission = 'DENIED' then count("permission") else 0 end as denied_count                                       
                     from table
                     group by 1,2
                     order by user_id
```

but take record in this way:

| user_id | denied_count | limited_count | permitted_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 25 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 139 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 139 | 0 | 3 | 0 |

please tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: Just get rid of "permission" in the select and group by. I think count() ought to behave how you are wanting it to. But if not sum(case when ... then 1 else 0 end) certainly will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with BigQuery. That syntax you are doing might be perfectly fine if you remove permission from the select and group by.

This is a pretty standard way to do it though:

https://dbfiddle.uk/liKLlSxH

```
CREATE TABLE permissions (
    user_id INT,
    permission VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (25, 'Denied');
INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (25, 'Permitted');
INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (139, 'Denied');
INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (139, 'Limited');
INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (139, 'Limited');
INSERT INTO permissions (user_id, permission) VALUES (139, 'Limited');

select user_id,
       sum(case when permission = 'Denied' then 1 else 0 end) as denied_count,
       sum(case when permission = 'Permitted' then 1 else 0 end) as permitted_count,
       sum(case when permission = 'Limited' then 1 else 0 end) as limited_count
  from permissions
 group
    by user_id;
```

Comment: You can even omit `else 0`.  The default value for a `case` is `null`, and aggregates like `sum` and even `count` ignore `null`

Comment: @Andomar Definitely, that is better. I figured being more explicit was good if OP is a beginner.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you a lot